# Multiply Dataframe column with a Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have DataFrame df =

```
      yyyymmdd                   Domain      Revenue
0     20210119                 Kurzy.cz   1.095453
1     20210119            agro-bazar.cz  25.641102
2     20210119             ahaonline.cz  45.217855
3     20210120                 Kurzy.cz   2.536259
4     20210120            agro-bazar.cz   1.282010
```

and I want to multiply column Revenue by Series of coeficients **based on date (yyyymmdd)**

```
coef = 
    yyyymmdd
    20210119    0.038140
    20210120    0.035556
    20210121    0.035793
    Name: CPMVS, dtype: float64
```

I tried variants of :

```
df['weighted'] = 1 / (df.groupby(by=['yyyymmdd', 'Domain'])['Revenue'] * coef)
```

but groupby return only groupbyObject, not Series nor DF.
When I do

```
df.mul(coef, axis=1)
```

it returns DF full of NANs.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` to substitute the values in the column `yyyymmdd` by the values from  the series `coeff`, then fill the `NaN` values *(values which can't be substituted)* with `1` and multiply it by the `Revenue` column:

```
df['Revenue'] = df['yyyymmdd'].map(coeff).fillna(1).mul(df['Revenue'])
```

---

```
   yyyymmdd         Domain   Revenue
0  20210119       Kurzy.cz  0.041781
1  20210119  agro-bazar.cz  0.977952
2  20210119   ahaonline.cz  1.724609
3  20210120       Kurzy.cz  0.090179
4  20210120  agro-bazar.cz  0.045583
```

Comment: Perfect! Earlier in the code I use `dropna()` so your `fillna` is redundant, but great for explanatory reasons.

Comment: Happy coding @smith007